# Smooth Scrolling a hero-unit of bootstrap page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to implement smooth scrolling in my website, but haven't been able to use any of the jquery plugins available, as i am not too acquainted with javascript.
Any help in this regard would be helpful.
Here is the relevant code:`

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="navigation">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2 ">
            <div class=" sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-fixed">
                <h4><a href="#about"  class="nav1 transition">About</a></h4>
                <h4><a href="#ourservices"  class="nav2 transition">Our Services</a></h4>
                <h4><a href="#awards"  class="nav3 transition">Awards</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "span10" style="margin-top:30px">
            <div class="hero-unit " >                                
                <div id="about" >
                    <h1 >About </h1>                                
                    <hr>
                    <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
                </div>
                <div id="ourservices" >
                    <h1 >Our Services</h1>                                
                    <hr>
                    <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="awards" >
                    <h1 >Awards</h1>                                
                    <hr>
                    <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My intention is to display on "about" section ...and when a user clicks on say services... the hero-unit scrolls to "services" section.
A detailed answer would be appreciated as i am not very acquainted with javascript.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iscroll plugin of jquery...
[Iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

I have used this in may mobile web-site : [smooth-scroll](http://m.getusedparts.com/home)

go to the year selection page..there is a smooth scroll implementation.